# How to publish for all target frameworks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core, csproj

I am building a set of build template in TeamCity for .Net Core projects. Everything is working great, except for console projects. The problem is that when I go to publish the solution, I need to specify the framework version. At no other point in the build do I need to know the framework. At least this is true when publishing .sln files, with a console project that only has a single framework targeted.

So now I am in a situation where I need to figure out what framework the console project should target. I could read various XML files, but I'm hoping I don't need to. Is there some builtin way that I can query for the frameworks in use for a given solution?

For example, something like (PowerShell)

```
$frameworks = & dotnet.exe --<what I want> .\MySolution.sln
for ($framework in $frameworks) {
  & dotnet.exe publish -f $framework .\MySolution.sln
}
```

That way I don't need to modify the build system every time a new framework is in use. I've poked around in the CLI repo, but I can't find a command that does what I need. Is opening .csproj files my only hope?

Comment: Have you looked at the project.json file this should have the information you are looking for

Comment: project.json is no longer supported and for VS2017 the information is available as `RuntimeIdentifier` property.. even though you could use msbuild evaluation to get it, this is tricky..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to publish projects that target multiple frameworks, the default `Publish` target fails, but you can create a custom target that performs the multi-targeting itself. To do this, create a file named `Directory.Build.props` in the solution folder (with MSBuild > 15.1 this can and should be named `Directory.Build.targets` because there [was a bug with multi-targeting projects](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1991)):

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="PublishProjectIfFrameworkSet"
          DependsOnTargets="Publish"
          Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != '' " />

  <Target Name="PublishProjectForAllFrameworksIfFrameworkUnset" Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == '' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_PublishFramework Include="$(TargetFrameworks)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Publish" Properties="TargetFramework=%(_PublishFramework.Identity)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishAll"
          DependsOnTargets="PublishProjectIfFrameworkSet;PublishProjectForAllFrameworksIfFrameworkUnset" />
</Project>
```

Then you can publish the projects for all defined frameworks by executing this in the solution directory:

```
$ dotnet msbuild /t:PublishAll /p:Configuration=Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  app2 -> /Users/martin/testproj/app2/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/app2.dll
  app1 -> /Users/martin/testproj/app1/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/app1.dll
  app1 -> /Users/martin/testproj/app1/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/app1.dll
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to not have to fall into msbuild directly, but this works. Thanks.

Comment: My thoughts exactly @ErickT... MSBuild is the JavaScript of the .NET ecosystem. :P  Seems like there would simply be a `--framework *` or equivalent here.